# MongoDB: fast search in a collection of very different objects

Tags: mongodb, search, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

Well, one of the main pros of MongoDB is the ability to maintain documents of different structures within a single collection. It'g realy great and useful for number of tasks.

I'm making an application that should search in a very big list of various goods. There are tens types of items and every item can have tens of properties. I want the searсh to be as flexible as possible and perform searching opeartions in database very fast. And i need to find out the best storade data model/architecture.
Lets say I have user queries like below:

1. Find items by their specific property (e.g. get all cars that are 4WD)
2. Find items that has specific property (e.g. get everything that is red colored)

Generally I'd state the problem as "I need to find items by some of hundreds of their properties". Maybe i'm wrong just here, let me know.
Max indexes to be applied to a Mongo collection is 64 and i guess i'll need more props to search by, so this way doesnt seem to solve my problem.
The alternatives i am thinking of are:

1. Besides the main collection that holds all goods data, create
   collections-per-type for use when searching, for example CarsHelper
   that have car type, weight, model, color etc as properties and there
   are indexes made on every of them. This will solve #1 but not #2.
2. Use full text searching engine like Lucene and store all properties
   as text in there.
3. Use some extra fields in the main collection that would hold props
   in a specific way so it won't require 64+ indexes to be created.

I think there are much more options than these three. I'l definitelly think of them, but if you already have ideas/links/suggessions for how to organize data in a better way, you help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: This is a very good question and I would appreciate if you share a solution (really :) ). Perhaps composite indexes could help a little.

Comment: Can you give just a little bit more detail? How many properties do you search on at once? Are some properties usually present in a query, while some are rare? What proportion of documents will have a given property `x` among the hundreds of properties? 1%? 10%? 50%? There's a number of options for you but I think I want some more information about the properties and how they'll be used before I recommend anything.